# css/js file reference error while rendering a page using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, get, httprequest

I'm trying to load a page using Node.js as a server.

I'm trying to crate an API that loads a different page accordingly with the user input.

I'm using the following code:

```
app.get('/apitest/:id', function(request, response) {

    const requestId = request.params.id;    

    if(requestId == 1){
        response.render('pages/index2');
    } else if(requestId == 2){
        response.render('pages/index3');
    } else{
        response.render('pages/404');
    }
});
```

The problem is that the js and css files included into the loaded pages cannot be found.
The reason is that the server looks for them at the wrong path which is the following one:

> http://localhost:5000/apitest/js/three/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js

But all the js/css files are in the folder public/js and public/css (classic server Node.js path).

So if I just load the page using

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {  
    response.render('pages/index');
});
```

everything works perfectly and the scripts are perfectly loaded, but if I try to use the the first snippet of code the server cannot find them anymore.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use absolute paths.

Comment: problem solved?

Comment: @taha actually I already have this line of code: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) buy it's not working. I also have tried your solution but it's not working.

Comment: when you tried my solution what kind of error did you get? what url express is generating for your static files?

Comment: @taha I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: try the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify a mount path :

```
// path should be required
`app.use('/apitest/:id', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`
```